# How to add OWIN Startup in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, owin

Hi i've added a owin startup class in my WCF service this

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SampleService.StartupClass))]

namespace SampleService
{
    public class StartupClass
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        }
    }
}
```

but it seems that the Configuration method is not firing i've tried this in a normal web application its working. but in WCF its not did i miss something? that's why its not firing my my WCF application kindly give your advice regarding this any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

WCF doesn't support OWIN yet. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx if you want to self host WCF and not use IIS.

Check out http://owin.org/#projects for the support projects of OWIN.