# Dependency injecting 'SignInManager' (Identity 2.0) with Ninject

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject, asp.net-identity

I am adapting ASP Identity authentification functionalitys to be called from a WCF web service.

I am using ninject for dependency injection across the project, so I have a custom class (UserProfilManager) witch i use to implement Identity functions by injecting  dependencies required by my constructor.

```
public class UserProfilManager
{
    private readonly UserStore _userStore;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser, Guid> _signInManager;

    public UserProfilManager(UserStore userStore, 
        UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid> userManager, 
        SignInManager<IdentityUser, Guid> signInManager)
    {
        _userStore = userStore;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    //here I call Identity functionality (PasswordSignInAsync), GetByLogin is a function ment to be called from WCF
    public async Task<SignInStatus> GetByLogin(string login, string password, bool RememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        return await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login, password, RememberMe, shouldLockout);
    }

    //FindByNameAsync function works fine, UserStore binding : OK
    public User GetByName(string login)
    {
        var user = _userStore.FindByNameAsync(login);
        return new User
        {
            //...
        };
    }
}
```

the 'UserStore' and the 'UserManager' bindings are done fine, but 'SignInManager' throws an ActivationException : 
**Error activating IAuthenticationManager, No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.**
I fixed it by adding this:

```
public class UserModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IDbContext>().To<DbContext>();

            Bind<IUserProfilManager>().To<UserProfilManager>();
            Bind<IUserStore<IdentityUser, Guid>>().To<UserStore>();

            Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().
                ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InRequestScope();

        }
    }
```

Now it's giving me this Error:

**The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.**

I don't have a startup class and I don't need it, I tried to top hip from searching that class by adding `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` in my WCF web.config but it throws an Internal Server Error :
**Failed to add a service. The metadata of the service may be unavailable. Make sure your service is running and exposes metadata.**

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, or suggest a solution based on my code.

Answer (score 2):

What you see here is OWIN trying to start itself around the web-server. But because you run WCF it can't do anything. Bascially OWIN says it can't run in WCF in the current configuration. `IAuthenticationManager` sets the cookie on HTTP Requests, but because WCF is not only HTTP, OWIN's cookie can't be applied.

So you need to review your architecture how your WCF service is authenticating and what it is going.

Looking on [other questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829824/809357), I don't [think you can make](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457458/809357) [OWIN work with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198935/does-owin-support-wcf). [But you can try...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24666823/809357)

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can configure OWIN when WCF is run?  In a simple Web App there is a startup class calling a method Configuration (IAppBuilder app) that does the job. Do you think I can do the same in WCF?

Comment: I don't think you can use WCF with OWIN. See edit for links to other similar questions.